# object draft10 is not a member of package com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2

Tags: scala, google-api, oauth-2.0, lift, sbt

I'm compiling the following code in scala:

https://gist.github.com/3236096

but it gives me the following error:

```
draft10 object is not a member of package
com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2
```

And this:

```
setApplicationName value is not a member of scala.runtime.StringAdd
```

I think the problem is that I need some packages.

I need help and I tell me please the following:

Repository that I can download the packages that I need

The package versions:

In my sbt I have the following packages:

```
GoogleApi lazy val = "google-api-services" at 
"http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg"

GoogleReleases lazy val = "Google Releases" at
"https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases"


"com.google.api-client"% "google-api-client"% "1.11.0-beta"
"com.google.apis"% "google-api-services-oauth2"% "1.3.3-beta-v2"
"com.google.api.client"% "google-api-client"% "1.3.1-alpha"
```

The problem is with: draft10, not where to get the package.

Thanks for your attention, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll point you to the javadoc: http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/draft10/package-summary.html

It says that the package draft10 is available since version 1.4. So update your sbt script to use version 1.4 instead:

```
"com.google.api-client"% "google-api-client"% "1.4"
```

Also, make sure that you don't try to use several versions of the same library. The script that you posted refers both to version 1.10.0-beta and versiom 1.3.1-alpha of google-api-client.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is:
 
for SBT

```
"com.google.apis"% "google-api-services-oauth2"% "rev9-v2-1.7.2-beta"
```

and the repository:

```
"http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/"
```